# KSH while loop causing issues

Tags: ksh

Hi guys I'm getting this error message when running my KSH script:

./file.sh: line 16: syntax error at line 22: `done' unexpected

My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#

count=$#           #count is assigned num of parameters
num=$1             #assign parameter 1 to num

if test count -gt 9 #make sure theres only 9 numbers
    then
       echo "Only 9 parameters allowed"
       exit
fi


echo "Number of Parameters you passed: $count"
printf  "$num + \c"
sum=$1

while test $count -ge 1
     shift 1     #move numbers 1 to left
     num=$1      #assign new value to num
     printf "num + \c"
done

((sum = sum + num))

echo "$num = $sum"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `do` keyword:

```
while ...; do
...
done
```

Comment: `((sum += num))` also works

Answer (score 3):

You need a `do` after the `while`:

```
while test $count -ge 1
do
   ...
done
```